# Google Scripts - SWITCH statement doesn't work with range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, scripting, switch-statement, spreadsheet

I'm working on a simple function that should return the quantity of specific elements in a passed range. I would like to use SWITCH statement but for some reason it doesn't work as I would expect:

```
function groupResult(range) {
  const resultsQuantity = {
    na: 0,
    fail: 0,
    pass: 0,
    empty: 0
  }
  for(let i of range) {
    switch(i){
      case 'N/A':
        resultsQuantity.na++;
        break;
      case "FAIL":
        resultsQuantity.fail++;
        break;
      case "PASS":
        resultsQuantity.pass++;
        break;
      default:
        resultsQuantity.empty++
    }
  }
  return resultsQuantity.na;
}
```

the function call in the spreadsheet looks like follows:
[call of the function in the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnV1B.png)

but as result I get "0" instead of expected "2"

Comment: `range` is a 2d array, modify to `for(let i of range.flat())`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
for(let i of range.flat())
```

Because the range is a 2d array.